# problems about regex match js template

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a code snippet like below:

```js
import VLink from '../../components/vlink/vlink'
export default {
  template: "<div class=\"about\">\n    <VLink></VLink>\n    <p>This is an about page.</p>\n</div>",
  components: {
      VLink
  },
  data () {
    return {

    };
  }
}

// import Vue from 'vue'
// import VLink from '../../components/vlink/vlink'

// export default {
//     template: __inline('home.html'),
//     components: {
//         VLink
//     }
// }
```

And I want to isolate the template value from the code which is not commented.It means that I just want to get the code of `<div class="about">...</div>` not the code of `__inline('home.html')` in comment. How can I achieve the goal by regex?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why are you processing your JS files with regexp?

Comment: I just want to translate the template to a render function.As you know, vue 2.0 had support the render function, and every template will compile to a render finally.I can also ignore the feature,and it will auto compile at runtime.I just want to process this at build time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[^\/]{2}\s*template:\s*(.*),
```

You will get the desired code captured in the group1.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oZkfXF/2

Comment: yeah, it works.Thank you. But I think i forget another case like: `/* ... */`

Comment: If 1st character is always space on the desired `template` line you can use this: `^\s*?template:\s*(.*),`